# My data is being printed all on one line while writing into a CSV file

Tags: python, csv

So here's the code I'm working with. When I open the tweetsentiment.csv file, the tweets are all printed out in one line. Also, I'm only getting every other line outputted into this file.

```
streamedtweets = open('tweetdb', 'r')
outputfile = []
for row in streamedtweets:
    stline = streamedtweets.readline() #do i need this?
    processedStreamed = processTweet(stline)
    streamedsentiment =  NBClassifier.classify(extract_features(getFeatureVector(processedStreamed)))
    outputfile.append((streamedsentiment, stline))
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\wildcat\Downloads\NLTK')

with open('tweetsentiment.csv', 'w', newline = '' ) as output:
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\wildcat\Downloads\NLTK')
    a = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',)
    data = [outputfile]
    a.writerow(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem is reading the lines, you are not doing it properly, try this example within your full code:

```
for stline in streamedtweets.readlines():
    processedStreamed = processTweet(stline)
    streamedsentiment =  NBClassifier.classify(extract_features(getFeatureVector(processedStreamed)))
    outputfile.append((streamedsentiment, stline))
    os.chdir(r'C:\Users\wildcat\Downloads\NLTK')
```

this way you are not mixing readline in the loop, but getting a single line in each loop pass.

Comment: Thanks!! This helped a lot, I had to add/fix some extra stuff but thanks for the huge start

Comment: Actually its still printing out every other line. I'm using `for stline in streamedtweets:`

Comment: I also tried ur implementation and it still skipped every other line

Answer (score 1):

The tweets are being printed into a single line because `writerow([outputfile])` writes a single row. Instead you can use the `writerows(outputfile)` method.

Example:

```
outputfile = [("positive", "a tweet"), ("negative", "a tweet")]
output = open("tweetsentiment.cvs", 'w')
writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',', lineterminator='\n',)
writer.writerows(outputfile)
```

This should give you the following output:

```
positive,a tweet
negative,a tweet
```

As for the second part of the question. No you do not need `streamedtweets.readline()`.
In fact the `readline()` in combination with using a for loop is why you are skipping rows since both of them move the file pointer forwards.

Comment: So how can I set up outputfile to be set up to every sentiment and tweet?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding what the issue is, but at a glance it seems like the first for loop should do that just fine if you remove the `readline()` call. This is assuming that the `tweetdb` file is formatted with one tweet per line.